# Why use functions like CGRectMake?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, compound-literals

I'm curious why functions like CGRectMake and CGPointMake exist and are widely used.
when, instead, you can do:

```
(CGRect){{x, y}, {width, height}}
```

surely this is more efficient (though I'm guessing not by much) as there is no function call?

Also you can set the origin and size like:

```
 (CGRect){origin, size}
```

and as a mixture:

```
 (CGRect){origin, {width, height}}
```

What is the reason for not using this, and preferring the Make functions?

Answer (score 13):

It isn't more efficient, actually. The `CGRectMake` function (and others) are declared as `static inline`, which means the compiler copy pastes the function code straight into every place it's used:

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
```

where

```
#  define CG_INLINE static inline
```

You go from

```
// code
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(1,2,3,4);
// code
```

to

```
// code
CGRect myRect;
myRect.origin.x = 1; myRect.origin.y = 2;
myRect.size.width = 3; myRect.size.height = 4;
```

which in principle is no different from

```
CGRect myRect = (CGRect){1,2,3,4};
```

after compiler optimizations and such.

As said above you add a dependency on `CGRect` being a struct of 4 numbers aligned a certain way as opposed to using a function that has more guarantee to it.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose it is the same old difference between:

1. adding a dependency in you code from the internal definition of a data structure;
2. using a function that encapsulates that knowledge and that could "mask" any changes in the underlying data structure.

In principle, `CGRect` might evolve into a full-blown class with its `origin`, `size,` etc, accessors, etc... I am not saying this would be sensible or that it is likely, only that the reason why you use a function to create instances of a data structure has to do with resilience of your code to changes.

Answer (score 6):

C99's Compound literal syntax is a *somewhat* obscure feature. Some people find the Make functions clearer to read, or they find it more familiar. At this stage in toolchain support, it's merely preference.

> I'm curious why functions like CGRectMake and CGPointMake exist…

`CGRectMake` (available since 10.0) preceded OS X's compiler's support of compound literals. Compound literals were officially completed in GCC 3.1 (May 2002).