# Define CGRectmake with CGPoint and/or CGSize

Tags: objective-c, syntax, cgrect, cgrectmake

This is a very simple question of which i can't seem to find the answer.
How to do this :

```
CGRectMake(1, 3, size)
```

or

```
CGRectMake(pointB, size)
```

or

```
 CGRectMake(pointB, size.width, size.height)
```

instead of

```
CGRectMake(self.someview.frame.origin.x, self.someview.frame.origin.y, self.someotherview.frame.size.width, self.someotherview.frame.size.height)
```

??
Thank you ! :)

EDIT:

The method `CGRectmake` takes `CGFloat`. I would like it to take `CGSize`, and/or `CGpoint` as arguments of the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a CGRect from a CGPoint and CGSize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063650/how-do-i-create-a-cgrect-from-a-cgpoint-and-cgsize)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you have in mind:

```
    - (void) logRects
    {
        CGFloat
            x      = 10.0,
            y      = 20.0,
            width  = 50.0,
            height = 60.0;

        CGPoint point = {x, y};
        CGSize  size  = {width, height};

        CGRect  rect1 = {1, 3, size};
        CGRect  rect2 = {point, size};
        CGRect  rect3 = {point, size.width, size.height};

            //using designated (named) initialisers
        CGRect  rect4 = {.origin.x=3, .origin.y=5, .size = {100,100}};

            //with designated initialisers, order doesn't matter
        CGRect  rect5 = {.size=size, .origin.x=3, .origin.y=5};

        NSLog (@"rect1 %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect1));
        NSLog (@"rect2 %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect2));
        NSLog (@"rect3 %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect3));
        NSLog (@"rect4 %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect4));
        NSLog (@"rect5 %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect5));
    }
```

But note the discussion here:
[Why use functions like CGRectMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700535/why-use-functions-like-cgrectmake)

This kind of compound literal syntax seems to me much easier to read and write, although functions have the edge when it comes to futureproofing ( + you get autocomplete).

*update*
see also this more recent q&a:

[CGRect syntax I haven't seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723747/cgrect-syntax-i-havent-seen-before)

Answer (score 6):

CGRectMake(1, 3, size):

```
    CGRectMake(1, 3, size.width, size.heigh)
```

CGRectMake(pointB, size):

```
    CGRectMake(pointB.x, pointB.y, size.width, size.height)
```

CGRectMake(pointB, size.width, size.height):

```
    CGRectMake(pointB.x, pointB.y, size.width, size.height)
```

A CGRect just looks like this:

```
struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

And CGPoint and CGSize just look like this:

```
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;

struct CGSize {
  CGFloat width;
  CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

CGRectMake is the following function:

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; 
  rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; 
  rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

So instead of:

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(pointB.x, pointB.y, size.width, size.height)
```

You can simply write:

```
CGRect r;

r.origin = pointB;
r.size = size;
```

If you feel like creating your own CGRectMake, feel free to do so:

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
MyPrivateCGRectMake(CGPoint p, CGSize s)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin = p;
  rect.size = s;
  return rect;
}
```

But there is no way you can change which arguments an already existing function accepts.

Comment: Actually that's what i want to avoid ! If you have pointB and size, why should you rewrite .x, .y, .width, or.height ? Your answers take CGFloats. I would like CGRectmake to take CGSize, and/or CGpoint int its method

Comment: @Plot `CGRectMake` behaves the way it has been defined, not the way you would like it to behave. `CGRectMake` simply doesn't work that way, it's not possible to change the way it works. You can write your own function if you like, `MyCGRectMake` that takes a point and a size as parameter, but there is no way you can change the parameters of `CGRectMake`.

Comment: You can define a macro, but you would still have to name it differently than `CGRectMake`, otherwise the macro would recursively call itself which leads to a compilation error.